# Juju charm, what to do when you can't reach archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: apt, juju, dns, archive, source-packages

I'm writing a Juju Charm for StrongSwan to auto-configure a VPN server.

One of the things I noticed with the CharmHelpers code is that the apt_update() function only checks for DPKG lock. I want to add some additional functionality.

I've seen apt-get update hang when it can't contact one of the archive servers. What I've done to remedy this is manually is do a DNS lookup for both security.ubuntu.com and archive.ubuntu.com and add these entries to my host file until one of them works. I will do this programatically as part of my install script.

Will security.ubuntu.com & archive.ubuntu.com always resolve to the same IP's or are additional checks necessary?

Is this the best way to build a charm? Should the package(s) be built into the charm (jumbo charm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your charm should obviously not rely on infrastructure details of the Ubuntu archive. Even if it works today, it might fail in the future.

I think your best bet is to raise a bug with charmhelpers at https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-helpers

You can also contribute with code if you feel like it, of course :)

Comment: Thanks. What would you recommend for installing the StrongSwan packages? I was using apt-get but I suppose I could use wget and build it from source.  The only thing with that is that the packages for 14.04 LTS are maintained, whereas installing from source could result in some inconsistencies. I added to the charmhelpers code so that if apt-get update or install timeout after x seconds it cycles through all the archive servers until one works. I'm not sure if this is something that other developers of charms would want?

Comment: Some charms handle that by having a "source" config option, where you specify from where you want the software to be fetched. It could have words like "distro", meaning the archive, or "ppa:some/url", meaning some ppa, or "upstream" meaning their git repo, for example.

Comment: This was really great advice Andreas, I appreciate your answer. I can install Strongswan from upstream source or the archives. However, my charm also has other dependencies where I rely heavily on the archives: CHARM_DEPENDENCIES = [
 "build-essential",
 "libssl-dev",
 "libffi-dev",
 "python-dev",
 "python3-pip"
]

Comment: If you know of a way to create and sign certificates in python without installing the pyOpenSSL library then please let me know ;-)